# Google Apps Script can't find created campaign

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-ads-api

The problem is I can create a campaign with the Apps Script which shows up in Ads Words Console, the problem is, I can't find it with the Apps Script API. All manually create Campaign can be found. So the question is how can I retrieve the newly created Ads Campaign id.

This is how I create the Ads Campaign, which runs through with no error. Once the code runs through it shows up in the Upload details view.

```js
var upload = AdsApp.bulkUploads()
    .newCsvUpload([
        "Campaign",
        "Start Date",
        "Budget",
        "Campaign type",
        "Bid Strategy Type",
        "Campaign state",
    ]);

upload.append({
    "Campaign": "Some Campaign name",
    "Start Date": "2020-06-01",
    "Budget": "1",
    "Campaign type": "video",
    "Bid Strategy Type": "Manual CPV",
    "Campaign state": "enabled",
});

upload.forCampaignManagement();
upload.apply();
```

To retrieve all campaigns I use this code snipped, but the created campaign never shows up.

```js
var campaignIterator = AdsApp.campaigns()
    .get();

while (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
    var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
    Logger.log('Name: ' + campaign.name);
}
```

Comment: If you have a lot of campaigns then perhaps you need to get more pages using the page token.

Comment: I've created a testing account where I have 5 campaigns, where that issue still exitst.